# Maui app displays black screen on iOS after splash screen, works fine on Windows and Android

Tags: maui, visual-studio-2022

I've developed a .NET Maui (Multi-platform App UI) application using Visual Studio 2022, and it functions flawlessly on both Windows and Android platforms. However, upon deploying the app to an iPad Pro running iOS, I encounter a frustrating issue. Following the splash screen display upon app launch, the screen transitions to a complete black screen instead of displaying the expected main application interface. This issue seems to be isolated to iOS devices. I've ensured that the navigation flow and screen transitions are correctly implemented in the codebase. Any assistance or insights into diagnosing and resolving this peculiar issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I'm seeking guidance on diagnosing and resolving this peculiar issue on iOS devices. Any insights or assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean when debugging on a physical device, you can see the splash screen at first but a black screen appears after that? What are the versions of Visual Studio, iOS and .NET?

Answer (score 0):

Does the Output window show anything? I was having the same problem and was getting this in the output window: `Microsoft.Maui.FileImageSourceService: Warning: Unable to load image file 'dotnet_bot.png'.` If this is the case you can remove the references to these images. While this is only a temporary fix it can get you back up and running. I will edit this if I can find a better fix.